No installed .NET SDK was found on the computer - Vscode (C# dev kit)
I am currently working on a C# GUI project on a dual-booted Windows/Manjaro machine. About a week ago I noticed that on the Manjaro partition, when I open my project through the "Right-Click Menu" then the following error appears:

No installed .NET SDK was found on the computer. If it is installed, make sure it can be found through the PATH environment variable. C# Dev Kit does not work without a supported version of SDK. After installing the SDK, you need to restart the VS code session, or the computer.

However if I open Vs code through the terminal then this error message doesn't appear and everything is fine.
This also does not happen in my Windows partition, regardless of how I open the project.
I'm not sure what is causing this. I have theories like, possibly for some reason Vs code is not getting the PATH variable correctly but I'm also unsure how to fix this.
I have tried changing the path in Vs code's settings like so:
"dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
    {
      "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
      "path": "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet"
    },
    {
      "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csdevkit",
      "path": "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.204"
    }

But this does not appear to have any effect.
My sdk version is 8.0.204 and is in /usr/share/dotnet/sdk
Lastly the Vs code I am using is from the AUR.

the terminal uses .bashrc and .profile while double clicking uses only .profile
